# Horizontal divs not aligning properly

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to make a wordpress theme with _s (underscores.me) as a starting point. I am not really good at wordpress or CSS but I have googled and tried to work this out this whole day.

So far I have produced the very basic result: (link removed)
I have a problem where the content-area is placed just a bit below the sidebar and the menu and I do not know why.

I have gone through the CSS and checked the header.php and the index.php files for hours without finding out why this happens.

[image]

*The red rectangle indicates the blank space I want to remove.*

Basically if someone can point me in the right direction I would be very happy.

I am not sure what code to include because I do not know where the problem lies in the code.

Comment: and the HTML looks like....?

Comment: What do you want me to include? The HTML for the whole front page? I am not sure what to include here..

Comment: Relevent HTML only. So if it is those 3 elements you're looking at, then we need the HTML to those 3 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `entry-title` has a margin (top and bottom).
So you can add :

```
.entry-title {
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I could not find any margins for `entry-title`. Where did you find this?

Comment: No problem. I used Chrome Dev tools

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  clear:both; to each div CSS that must park next to another div, regardless of its column position. Divisions do not inherit this property from each other or a parent.